# Calculating means based on conditionals for another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like

```
df <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("04/23/90", "04/28/90", "05/03/95", "05/07/95"
), class = "factor"), JULIAN = c(113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 
113L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L), ID = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("AHFG-01", "AHFG-02", 
"AHFG-03", "OIUR-01", "OIUR-02", "OIUR-03"), class = "factor"), 
    PERCENT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 80L, 55L, 0L, 25L, 50L, 75L, 100L, 
    75L, 45L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 75L, 
    90L, 95L)), .Names = c("DATE", "JULIAN", "ID", "PERCENT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))

    DATE     JULIAN ID      PERCENT
1   04/23/90    113 AHFG-01 0
2   04/23/90    113 AHFG-02 0
3   04/23/90    113 AHFG-03 0
4   04/23/90    113 OIUR-01 80
5   04/23/90    113 OIUR-02 55
6   04/23/90    113 OIUR-03 0
7   04/28/90    118 AHFG-01 25
8   04/28/90    118 AHFG-02 50
9   04/28/90    118 AHFG-03 75
10  04/28/90    118 OIUR-01 100
11  04/28/90    118 OIUR-02 75
12  04/28/90    118 OIUR-03 45
13  05/03/95    123 AHFG-01 10
14  05/03/95    123 AHFG-02 20
15  05/03/95    123 AHFG-03 30
16  05/03/95    123 OIUR-01 50
17  05/03/95    123 OIUR-02 50
18  05/03/95    123 OIUR-03 50
19  05/07/95    127 AHFG-01 50
20  05/07/95    127 AHFG-02 60
21  05/07/95    127 AHFG-03 70
22  05/07/95    127 OIUR-01 75
23  05/07/95    127 OIUR-02 90
24  05/07/95    127 OIUR-03 95
```

In this dataframe, `ID` gives replicates at different sites. For example, `AHFG-01` is replicate 1 and `AHFG-02` is replicate 2, both at site `AHFG`. `PERCENT` refers to percent completion.

I need to calculate two things:
**1)** Mean `JULIAN` when `PERCENT` first exceeds 50 for *each* site, across years
**2)** Mean `JULIAN` when `PERCENT` first exceeds 50 for *all* sites, across years

I am a bit baffled about the best way to proceed here. My approach is to:
**1)** Calculate mean `PERCENT` for each site (from `ID`) at each `DATE`/`JULIAN`
**2)** Identify `JULIAN` when mean `PERCENT` first exceeds 50, for each site for each `YEAR` 
**3)** Calculate mean `JULIAN` from **2)** for *each* site across years
**4)** Calculate mean `JULIAN` from **2)** for *all* sites across years

For the datamrame above, the end results I need by site and for sites together would look something like this:

```
SITE    JULIAN
AHFG    122.5
OIUR    120.5

JULIAN, all sites combined = 121.5
```

What I have done so far is first create columns `YEAR` and `SITE` to use for operations:

```
df$DATE <- as.POSIXct(df$DATE, format='%m/%d/%y')
df$YEAR <- format(df$DATE, format='%Y')
df$SITE <- gsub("[^aA-zZ]", " ", df$ID)
```

Then I can use `aggregate` to calculate `SITE` means for step 1 above:

```
df2 <- aggregate(PERCENT ~ SITE + JULIAN + YEAR,FUN=mean,data=df)
```

However, I am getting stuck at step 2 and beyond. Can anyone suggest a way to calculate the mean `JULIAN` when `PERCENT` first exceeds 50, for each `SITE` across years, and all combined `SITE`s across years?

**Solution:**

Here is a modified form of Hekrik's excellent solution that is working for me. Note that Henkik's original solution did work but my question was a bit unclear on what I wanted (see comments below).

```
# make year column
df$DATE <- as.POSIXct(df$DATE, format='%m/%d/%y')
df$YEAR <- format(df$DATE, format='%Y')

# make new ID column (remove numbers for individuals)
df$SITE <- gsub("[^aA-zZ]", " ", df$ID)

# Calculate average PERCENT for each SITE
df2 <- aggregate(PERCENT ~ SITE + JULIAN + YEAR,FUN=mean,data=df)

# order by SITE and JULIAN
df2 <- df2[order(df2$SITE, df2$JULIAN), ]

# within each YEAR and SITE, select first registration where PERCENT is 50 or more
df2 <- do.call(rbind,
               by(df2, list(df2$YEAR, df2$SITE), function(x){
                 x[x$PERCENT >= 50, ][1, ]
               }))

# calculate mean JULIAN per SITE
aggregate(JULIAN ~ SITE, data = df2, mean)

# overall mean
mean(df2$JULIAN)
```

Comment: what is the difference between "for each site" and "for all sites" ... just to give one example of what is obscure to me

Comment: Dear  Яaffael, "for each site" is AHFG and OIUR separately, while "for all sites" is AHFG and OIUR together. So, in the "end results" given above, you can see that I've given means for AHFG (122.5), OIUR (120.5), and AHFG and OIUR together (121.5). I hope this makes sense - sorry for the confusion, sometimes I am not very clear.

Comment: I can only speak for myself but trying to understand your question exceeds my limit of one minute.

Comment: Since you have multiple replicates at each date and site, is your baseline date the date when percentage exceeds 50 for *any one of the replicates* or when *the average percentage* exceeds 50?? If it is the former, for example, then for SITE=OIUR this happens on the first date (4/23/90).

Comment: I am looking for the date when the average percentage equals 50

Comment: In your original question you wrote "first **exceeds** 50", that's why I used `> 50` and not `>= 50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
# order by SITE and DATE
df <- df[order(df$SITE, df$DATE), ]


# within each YEAR and SITE, select first registration where PERCENT exceeds 50
df2 <- do.call(rbind,
               by(df, list(df$YEAR, df$SITE), function(x){
                 x[x$PERCENT > 50, ][1, ]
               }))
df2
#          DATE JULIAN      ID PERCENT YEAR SITE
# 6  1990-04-28    118 AHFG-03      75 1990 AHFG
# 11 1995-05-07    127 AHFG-02      60 1995 AHFG
# 13 1990-04-23    113 OIUR-01      80 1990 OIUR
# 22 1995-05-07    127 OIUR-01      75 1995 OIUR


# calculate mean JULIAN per SITE
aggregate(JULIAN ~ SITE, data = df2, mean)
#   SITE JULIAN
# 1 AHFG  122.5
# 2 OIUR  120.0


# overall mean
mean(df2$JULIAN)
# [1] 121.25
```

Please note that I don't get the same mean for OIUR as in your example.

Comment: Thanks Henrik! It is strange though that the mean for OIUR is 120.0, instead of 120.5.  I doubled-checked my example and it should indeed be 120.5.  I tried using "x$PERCENT >= 50" (to take values equal to 50) and that gives a mean of 118 for OIUR. I'm not sure why this is happening. I think perhaps this method is using individuals (not site means) and am looking into that now.

Comment: Dear Henrik, I made a couple of edits to your code and it now appears to work properly for me. I will update my original post with the solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I went through `df` manually, and the values in `df2` seem OK. If I have understood your question correctly...

Comment: Hello Henrik, I believe in your solution, the "select first registration" was using individual values, but instead I wanted the site average for individuals. I also changed ">" to ">=" to use greater than or equal to 50. My original question was unclear, sorry for that.  Thanks again for your help!